# Failed to send email from contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, email, send, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 one of my wordpress site that using vantage app theme. But problem with sending contact mail. when I am trying to send mail get following message

"Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method."

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is you can send emails from you hosting domain email accounts only.

so check your to email address that is comes under you domain name

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly due to your particular hosting setup. There are a host of issues that can stop the sending of emails. It depends entirely on your local Server & WordPress configuration.

You will need to investigate this issue for your particular local configuration. See [Contact Form 7 Email Issues](http://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/#Contact_Form_7_Email_Issues).

*By the way it's not due to "hosting php version or maybe mysql version" - it's due to basic stuff that you can address by working through the issues in the link.*

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion depends on how your hosting provider deals with mail headers:

So, I have made all tests (javascript conflicts, etc.) and decided the problem could only be from my host. I contacted them and they told me that in email header, the "From:" SHOULD be exactly the same as the email I configured to receive the messages from my visitors.

As far as I understood, by default "Contact Form 7" uses visitor email to put it in "From:" but some host providers do not allow that.

My host provider don't even allow mail() function so I had to install WP MAIL SMTP.

So, resuming, I just added this to all my forms in "Additional headers":

From: your@domain.com

This means, you have to insert one email with same domain name as your website, otherwise your hosting might not send the email.

I lost a couple of hours with this...

Comment: I cannot understand how someone downvoted this because this actually happened with me and has worked ever since...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue some time back. Are you using any WordPress caching plugin? like WP super-cache? I resolved this issue by following below steps on WP Super-cache.

- Go to WP Super-Cache Admin panel
- Go to “Advanced Tab”
- Search for “Add here strings (not a filename) that forces a page not to be cached.”
- Add '/contact/' (your Contact Form Page name)
- Save Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem after I spoke to my client's hosting company. The host claimed that the only requirement they had for emails to be passed through their system was that either the To: or the From: field contain an email address under the hosted domain name. They uploaded a test script (an ordinary PHP mail script) where the From: field was set with an address within the domain and the To: field was set to an outside email address. That script worked. I confirmed that I had the To: field in CF7 set to an email address within the appropriate domain but the form didn't function. Then I set the From: field to an email address within the domain and the form finally functioned. It appeared, therefore, that the host was incorrect about the To: field's address being within the domain being sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Into the "Form"(inside the mail menu) section you've to give the domain name of your site. And inside the message body use the short codes which will appear into the top of the mail menu.
And when you create a form field such as "name" / "email" / "phone no" etc, then give a name to them. Those name turns into a short codes like
[your-name]-Name,  [your-mail]-Email(those are defaults, you can give any name according to your choice) etc, copy the short code and paste into the message body, don't write it only copy and paste. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe is another plugin incompatible with contact form7 plugin.
Deactivate all plugin one by one and try send email.

Comment: I tried but still not working. But it is working well in my another server with same theme. is it hosting problem?

Comment: then is from hosting php version. or maybe mysql version. check that both servers and tell me which work wich not. check also theme version, plugins version...that could be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem. webadmin email account was not setup. Once I setup the email account it is working fine.